# How do I make every other line move one up on Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a 150-line long data file like so:

```
T
6
13
6
20
13
6
13
...
```

I would like to move every other line one up like so:

```
T,6
13,6
20,13
6,13
...
```

How do I do this on Notepad++ (or any other program)? Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I see your downvote. Is the question too juvenile for the community?

Comment: Are you sure of the result? I guess it should be `T,6` `8,13` `6,20` `13,6`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to well understand the rules, I guess you want:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^,\r\n]+)\R`
- Replace with: `$1,`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  (             : start group 1
    [^,\r\n]+   : negative character class, 1 or more char that is not comma or line break
  )             : end group 1
\R              : any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1,             : group 1 then a comma
```

**Result for given example:**

Not exactly what you gave in the question

```
T,6
8,13
6,20
13,6
13,...
```